# How to write Custom object to firestore in Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this custom Object that I want to write to firestore, but I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'CheckboxModel'

My two Classes:

```
class TaskModel {
  String taskId;
  String taskTitle;
  String taskColor;
  DateTime taskDateEdit;
  List<CheckboxModel> checkboxItems;
}
```

```
class CheckboxModel{
  String checkboxContent;
  bool isDone;
}
```

and this is the method to write to firestore:

```
void addTask(TaskModel task){
    String _uid = _firebaseService.auth.currentUser.uid;

     _firebaseService.firestore
        .collection("users")
        .doc(_uid)
        .collection("tasks")
        .doc(task.taskId)
        .set(task.toMap());
  }
```

Any help suggestion on how I should approach this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You already have a `task.toMap()` call in there. Can you show how you implemented the `toMap` function?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen 

Here's the 'toMap()' method inside my TaskModel class: 

`Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "task_id": taskId == null ? null : taskId, "task_title": taskTitle == null ? null : taskTitle, "task_color": taskColor == null ? null : taskColor, "task_date_edit":  taskDateEdit == null ? null : taskDateEdit.toIso8601String(), "task_items": checkboxItems == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(checkboxItems.map((x) => x)), };`

I used [this generator](https://app.quicktype.io/)

Comment: Good to see below that you've found a solution. In the future, please add clarifying code to the question instead of in a comment, as it's really hard to parse otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: (TaskModel class)

toMap method:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "task_id": taskId == null ? null : taskId,
        "task_title": taskTitle == null ? null : taskTitle,
        "task_color": taskColor == null ? null : taskColor,
        "task_date_edit":
            taskDateEdit == null ? null : taskDateEdit.toIso8601String(),
     ->     "task_items": checkboxItems == null
            ? null
            : this
                .checkboxItems
                .map((checkboxItem) => checkboxItem.toMap())
                .toList() <-
      };
```

fromMap method:

```
factory TaskModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => TaskModel(
        taskId: json["task_id"] == null ? null : json["task_id"],
        taskTitle: json["task_title"] == null ? null : json["task_title"],
        taskColor: json["task_color"] == null ? null : json["task_color"],
        taskDateEdit: json["task_date_edit"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["task_date_edit"]),
       -> checkboxItems: json["task_items"] == null
            ? null
            : List<CheckboxModel>.from(
                json["task_items"].map(
                  (itemAsMap) => CheckboxModel(
                      checkboxContent: itemAsMap["checkbox_content"],
                      isDone: itemAsMap["is_done"]),
                ),
              ),  <-
      );
```